# Kernel panics randomly OSX 10.9.5

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

Could someone decrypt this so I can understand what is randomly crashing my Macbook Pro 13" Early 2011 please?

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff802cedcc1d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802cea3b19, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffffa041277ad0, CR3: 0x0000000072153057, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000001, RBX: 0xffffffa041277aa8, RCX: 0xffffff8050725450, RDX: 0x0000000000000821
RSP: 0xffffff8217e43d20, RBP: 0xffffff8217e43d50, RSI: 0x000000004463b6a5, RDI: 0xffffff8031807e40
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff8217e43ed0, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0x0000000002c89fc0
R12: 0xffffff8031807e40, R13: 0xffffff802f790000, R14: 0x0000000002aa8000, R15: 0xffffff805e0b9a00
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0xffffff802cea3b19, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffffa041277ad0, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8217e439b0 : 0xffffff802ce23139 
0xffffff8217e43a30 : 0xffffff802cedcc1d 
0xffffff8217e43c00 : 0xffffff802cef4486 
0xffffff8217e43c20 : 0xffffff802cea3b19 
0xffffff8217e43d50 : 0xffffff802ce787be 
0xffffff8217e43f20 : 0xffffff802cedd05c 
0xffffff8217e43fb0 : 0xffffff802cef438b 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Safari

Mac OS version:
13F1077

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Wed Mar 18 16:20:14 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2422.115.14~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: ...
Kernel slide:     0x000000002cc00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802ce00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 ...

System uptime in nanoseconds: 79050012969089
last loaded kext at 62691502197523: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1 (addr 0xffffff7faed0b000, size 348160)
last unloaded kext at 51888758104512: com.vmware.kext.vmci  90.4.18 (addr 0xffffff7faeced000, size 73728)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.6.22
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.7f4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.10
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.2
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D314131333333433920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f4 15112, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Crucial_CT480M500SSD1, 480,1 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The main points of this kernel panic are analogous to the mathematical direction to divide 5 by 0

The kernel / core of the OS got an instruction that cannot make sense, so it dumps all it knows about what it sees looking backwards and forces the user to start over.

The kext are kernel extensions and you sometimes can catch one that causes this. Similarly, the page fault (type 14) has to do with memory access. Similarly, if you have the source code you can sometimes use the backtrace to see what code was running on that CPU before the problem was raised.

Other times, the problem has messed up the logic so that none of the values make any sense.

You may notice that I'm not giving you a precise answer. That's because you usually need Apple's assistance to make sense of any particular log file - and even if you give them 10 log files with 10 corresponding panics, sometimes it's not clear what's causing it.

Can you ask a follow on question with specific request - like how to disable the VMware kernel extension or how to make sense of a pattern of crashes (you'll need to summarize them and compare the type of fault, possibly the BSD process name corresponding to current thread (and sometimes this is an innocent bystander and not the culprit) as well as any patterns of the kext activity.

You can learn more about debugging a KP from this excellent but technically challenging article:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2063/_index.html